# how to implement app id in app subscription android

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

i have followed some example for in app subscription but i am not sure that where to put app_id which is generated in google play store ..please help me for this small thing..

this my class this work for test but don't know how to implement in real case

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

private WebView webView;
private Button subscription;
IInAppBillingService mservice;
ServiceConnection connection;
String inappid = "android.test.purchased";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    connection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mservice = null;

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mservice = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };

    bindService(new Intent(
            "com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
            connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}



public void showDialog(View v) {
    ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
            skuList.add(inappid);
            Log.i("TAG", "CLICK");
            Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
            querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
            Bundle skuDetails;
            try {
                skuDetails = mservice.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(),
                        "inapp", querySkus);

                int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                if (response == 0) {

                    ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails
                            .getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                    for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                        Log.i("PRICE_TAG", thisResponse);
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                        String sku = object.getString("productId");
                        String price = object.getString("price");
                        if (sku.equals(inappid)) {
                            System.out.println("price " + price);
                            Bundle buyIntentBundle = mservice
                                    .getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku,
                                            "inapp",
                                            "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle
                                    .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                            startIntentSenderForResult(
                                    pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001,
                                    new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0),
                                    Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Remote erroer",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "json error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sending intent error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString(inappid);
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "You have bought the " + sku
                                + ". Excellent choice,adventurer!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),
                        "Failed to parse data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (connection != null) {
        unbindService(connection);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    showDialog(arg0);

}
```